# Getting error when set rasa-x admin password with default command

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

I have deployed RASA open-source and Rasa-x in docker-compose. When setting the admin password for rasa-x using this command, getting an error.

```
sudo python rasa_x_commands.py create --update admin me admin
```

### Error:

```
File "rasa_x_commands.py", line 102
    command = f"delete {args.username}"
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go > cd /etc/rasa/

Execute following command:

```
docker-compose exec rasa-x bash -c “python3 /app/scripts/manage_users.py create me welcome123 admin --update”’
```

Added `--update` at the end because it gave me the below error message without `--update`:

> User ‘me’ already exists. You can update the password by running
>
> ```
> sudo python rasa_x_commands.py create --update me admin <new_pw>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
sudo python3 rasa_x_commands.py create --update admin system_user <new_pwd>

The deafult user "me" is not always working.
I am also not able to create a new user by using:

sudo python3 rasa_x_commands.py create admin <new_user> <new_pwd>